# Error Operator '&' is not defined for string "" and type 'Range'.'?

Tags: vb.net, concatenation

I receive the Error : **Operator '&' is not defined for string "" and type 'Range'.'** for the following Syntax:

```
str = str & Rng.Cells(Cel.Row - 1, 7) & ","
```

Where str is a string in which I want to concatenate text in column no 7
so how should I write this syntax in VB.net?

Comment: Try something closer to str = String.Concat(str, rng.cells(cel.row-1,7),",")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a `.Text` field:

```
str = str & Rng.Cells(Cel.Row - 1, 7).Text & ","
```

Please let me know if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks, it needed .Text